# How to call stopPropagation in Typescript

Tags: d3.js, typescript, stoppropagation

I'm trying to use stopPropagation method. I use d3.js with d3.d.ts (downloaded via `typings`). Is it possible to call `stopPropagation` somehow? I used `event.stopPropagation()` until I've run my application in firefox. Typings does have `d3.event` but it doesn't contain declaration of mentioned method.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It wasn't that hard actually. For `stopPropagation` I needed:

```
(d3.event as Event).stopPropagation();
```

The typings says that:

```
event: Event | BaseEvent
```

So essentialy event can be any of those. I've forgotten how union works in typescript. As the `type` property is only one common among `Event` and `BaseEvent` it was displayed solely. The one case when I needed cast to `BaseEvent` (I believe it is only used by d3) was on the `dragstart` event.

Comment: Of all the answers.... the easiest works (d3.event as Event).stopPropogation().... good answer

Comment: I think the typings might not be working for event anyhow

Answer (score 2):

You can narrow the type by doing a type guard style check:

```
if (d3.event instanceof Event) {
}
```

More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/typeGuard.html